# How to restrict user account based on website?

Tags: magento-1.9, permissions, user-roles, user-account

How to restrict user account based on website? How to create website wise user account in magento 1.9.2.3?

Comment: If you have multiple websites then you do not have to do anything. User will comes websites.

Comment: User account means not customer, internal user account like System->Permission->user

Answer (score 1):

You can set customer account scope from admin panel.
Go to System->Configuration->Customer Configuration->Account Sharing Option. Here Set **Share Customer Account** to **Per Website**.
Hope it helps

Ref: https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/customers/account-scope.html

Comment: User account means not customer, internal user account like System->Permission->user

Comment: You could use an extension https://marketplace.magento.com/aitoc-advanced-permissions.html or another way is customizing the code. For each module you have to customize the code  like example showed here for Order Grid. http://pixelpaul.net/magento-restrict-admin-order-website-store-view-certain-user-role/